# Hide iOS application Icons on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Prior to iOS 8.3,the plist tags

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
  <array>
    <string>hidden</string>
  </array>
```

.. Hid the app icon, This feature is deprecated on IOS 8.3

Any alternate Solutions?

P.S. Application is meant to run on non Jailbroken Devices, and is not meant for the Appstore.

Comment: look here http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=5072

Comment: Thank you for the link, however all solutions stated on that link have deprecated as of IOS 8.3 thats why i had to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intend to upload yours app to Appstore , then may be below process will be your answer -

1. Create a completely transparent PNG file, and use it as Icon. Enable the "Prerendered" checkbox to make sure no gradient is applied to your icon.
2. In your .plist file, remove the string "${PRODUCT_NAME}" from "Bundle display name"

Comment: Thank you @Santu I have tried that approach as well, However, the Transparent parts of the image will be completely black. even with prerendering checkbox turned off.